# Tapestry class loader with Tomcat and maven

Tags: maven, tapestry, tomcat7

Is it possible to integrate tapestry for class loading only under tomcat7 and eclipce, if so, how?
I am interesting in that for making java development alot faster.
My project is consists of:

- Spring MVC+JSP
- Maven
- String Security
- Mysql
- Hibernate
- log4j
- Tomcat7
- Eclipse
- helios
- ExtJs

I am looking for a stuation where I can save the java file and refresh the browser for seeing results/changes. (Like Jrebel).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone on the mailing list says it's possible, however i haven't gotten it to work 100%. You need to figure out how to point tomcat to various locations to find resources and not copy resources and libraries into the webroot folder. try asking on the mailing list for more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jetty + tapestry for it. And use tomcat7 only to production and tests.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it's possible and it works well. We (at tynamo.org) have a whole [guide available for using Maven, Eclipse, Tomcat7 and Tapestry together](http://tynamo.org/Developing+with+Tomcat+and+Eclipse), just follow the steps. Tomcat7 is easily as fast, perhaps faster starting up than Jetty.